# MySQL count a field into two different count results

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

I'm trying to COUNT attendance_status of drivers according to its value.
this is my code as of moment.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(attendance_status) AS total_cars_dispatched
FROM driver_attendance da 
LEFT JOIN collectible co ON (da.driver_attendance_id=co.driver_attendance_id)
LEFT JOIN driver_pondo dp ON (dp.collectible_id=co.collectible_id)
WHERE attendance_status=19 AND company_id=84 GROUP BY attendance_date DESC
```

I'd like to know how to make another COUNT of attendance_status when it's value is 4 using a single query.

Comment: Can you post your table structure with sample input data and desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT attendance_date, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN attendance_status = 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_cars_dispatched, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN attendance_status = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS attendance_status_4
FROM driver_attendance da 
LEFT JOIN collectible co ON da.driver_attendance_id=co.driver_attendance_id
LEFT JOIN driver_pondo dp ON dp.collectible_id=co.collectible_id
WHERE company_id=84 
GROUP BY attendance_date DESC;
```

Comment: it worked! thanks man, even if i failed to post the structure cause you've already answered it. uhm, additional question, what does the part--> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END meant?

Comment: This defines the outcomes of the `CASE`: `1` for the value actually checked for (here 19 and 4), `0` for anything `ELSE`. `END` is the end of the `CASE`.